# iOS 7 Creating Image thumbnails in threads not showing up in view unless tapped or after waiting a long time

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, ios7

I have a ViewController that displays a grid with image thumbnails. The thumbnails must be created on the fly so I am using an Activity Indicator together with some threading. This process works perfectly in iOS 5 and iOS 6 but when testing on iOS 7 it doesn't work so smoothly.

Here is the pertinent code:

```
- (void) displayItemsOnGrid:(NSArray *)items  {
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(displayItemsOnGridAsync:) withObject:items];
}

- (void) displayItemsOnGridAsync:(NSArray *)items {
    for (Item *item in items){
        GridItem *gridItem = HEAVY DUTY OPERATIONS;

        [self.view performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addSubview:) withObject:gridItem waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
}
```

The reason why I am going back to the main thread is because I want the thumbnails to appear as they are being processed instead of having them appear all at the end.

Like I said, this works perfectly on iOS 5 and 6 but when I run on iOS 7 the thumbnails only appear if I tap on the screen or if I wait an unacceptable amount of time. I've tried using GCD but I get the same exact result. What am I not seeing?

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

**INTERESTING FACT:**

If I change the code to:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addGridItemButton:) withObject:gridItemButton waitUntilDone:NO];
```

where:

```
- (void) addGridItemButton:(GridItem *) gridItemButton{
    [self.view addSubview:gridItemButton];
}
```

If I set a breakpoint right at:

```
[self.view addSubview:gridItemButton];
```

- In iOS 6: each thumbnail appears right after passing the breakpoint
- In iOS 7: nothing happens unless I tap on the screen or wait a long time for them to appear all together. (NO CLUE!)

---

**CHANGES USING GCD**

```
- (void) displayItemsOnGrid:(NSArray *)items  {
    [self displayItemsOnGridAsync: items];
}

- (void) displayItemsOnGridAsync:(NSArray *)items {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
        for (Item *item in items){
            GridItem *gridItem = HEAVY DUTY OPERATIONS;
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self addGridItemButton:gridItemButton];
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Again, this works fine in iOS 6 and not in iOS 7.

Comment: Have you tried performing the selector / dispatching the GCD block asynchronously?  Doing it synchronously from a bunch of different threads at once might cause performance bottlenecks.

Comment: Hi Sapi, I've tried doing the way they suggest in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871908/view-does-not-appear-because-of-ios-7 using dispatch_async and it takes a long time and the thumbnails don't appear as they are processed, they only appear at the end or also when tapping on the view (which I don't understand).

Comment: I've seen similar behaviour, but always when I've forgotten to do the update on the main thread.  `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue` works nicely for me.  Have you tried calling `setNeedsLayout` or `setNeedsUpdateSubviews` (or whichever is appropriate) on the view, to actually cause a redraw?

Comment: @sapi I have not done that. Let me give it a try and get back to you. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: @sapi I've given it a try and it doesn't change the behavior. Not sure what else to do at this point. Thanks so much for all your input and for sticking by.

Comment: Does your main thread wait on anything, ever?  That can cause all sorts of fun bugs :)  Generally when you're dealing with multiple threads in objc, you should make everything asynchronous unless *absolutely* necessary (hence why there's so many delegates flying around).

Comment: @sapi I'm trying to figure that out. Not yielding anything yet though. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @sapi you can check my response to Matt in his answer. It was definitely an operation within the thread that was giving problems. It was apparently overlooked in previous versions of iOS. Thanks for all your help on this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the symptoms you describe (nothing happens until tap, takes a long time, etc.) are *sure* signs of threading trouble. Either you are not really doing your updating on the main thread or you are locking up your threads in some other way.

One obvious problem is this line:

```
[self.view performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addSubview:) 
     withObject:gridItem 
     waitUntilDone:YES];
```

You should *not* be waiting until done. You are basically blocking your secondary thread waiting on the main thread, and this can get you into all sorts of trouble. You are throwing away a main reason for multithreading.

On the whole I would *strongly* recommend rewriting your code to use GCD (or operations, at the very least). `performSelectorInBackground:` and `performSelectorOnMainThread:` are very good ways to get yourself into trouble. With GCD you have serial cues and near-automatic prevention of data sharing.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks very much for the insight. I've tried "waitUntilDone:NO" as well, for that reason and nothing changes.I've also tried using GCD to no avail, same exact result. I'll post an edit with the new code so that maybe it could shed light into the situation. One thing that confuses me a bit is why the difference in behavior from iOS to iOS. Thanks again. Will post in a bit.

Comment: You're still clogging up your threads, by calling `dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0)`. That is a concurrent queue, so you're making a log jam. Use a serial queue of your own, not one of the built-in global queues.

Comment: Plus how do I know that your `HEAVY DUTY OPERATIONS` are safe against concurrent threads?

Comment: OK, I'll try with my own serial queue and get back to you. With regards to the operations, they are graphic operations that build the thumbnails by scaling images. They create a `UIButton` but never update the UI, that is done on the main thread. I can post the code but it's pretty long, that's why I omitted it, but you are right there could be something in there.  Thanks again.

Comment: I found the culprit. It was this line of code among the `HEAVY DUTY OPERATIONS`: `[gridItemButton setImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];` I truly thought I was not updating the UI because the button was not yet theoretically in the UI. I also ended up using GCD as you suggested on all of my previous threading. Let me know how we can update the answer so that it reflects this change and other people can benefit further from it. Thanks so much for all your help @matt and @sapi

Comment: @sunshineDev Feel free to add an answer to your own question. That's a very good way to show people your conclusions without messing up your original question. Glad you got this sorted out.

Comment: Thanks matt. I've accepted your answer, is it ok if I add an additional one to clarify even if it won't be the accepted one? Don't want to create more confusion. Your insight and that of @sapi were of great help to me but I agree that it would be positive to provide more detail in an answer.

Comment: @sunshineDev Definitely okay to add your own answer. You don't have to accept it (i.e. if you still want to award me the tickmark), but you can if you like, plus people can upvote your answer if it helps them too!

Answer (score 0):

As @matt and @sapi suggested, I went the way of GCD for performing my asynchronous operation of creating the thumbnails. Among other advantages, it allowed me to simplify the code and actually pinpoint what was going on and why I had this issue. For more information on migrating from threads to GCD you can check out the [Concurrency Programming Guide - Migrating Away from Threads](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW1)

As has been well documented, UI updates must always be done within the Main Thread. I hadn't realized that within what I denoted as my `HEAVY DUTY OPERATIONS` I was doing just that:

```
[gridItemButton setImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Even though the button has yet to be added to any view, it seems that this operation must still be performed within the Main Thread, if not it can definitely cause some problems, which apparently weren't being detected in previous `iOS` versions.

So, after updating my code, it now looks something like this:

```
- (void) displayItemsOnGrid:(NSArray *)items  {
    dispatch_queue_t queue;
    queue = dispatch_queue_create("thumbqueue", NULL);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        [self displayItemsOnGridAsync:items];
    });
}

- (void) displayItemsOnGridAsync:(NSArray *)items {
    for (Item *item in items){
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(size.itemWidth, size.itemHeight), NO, 0.0);

        //HEAVY DUTY UIKit OPERATIONS FOR SCALING, CROPPING, ETC.
        newImage =  = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            gridItemButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

            [gridItemButton setImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [self.view addSubview:gridItemButton];
        });
    }
}
```

Hope this helps clarify everything.